# extension Dictionary with Swift

Tags: swift

```
extension Dictionary{
    var postDic:String{
        let date = NSDate.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
        let timestamps = date.timeIntervalSince1970
        let v = String(timestamps)
        var tempDic = self
        tempDic["v"] = v
        return "123"
    }
}
```

there is an error

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your objects to key, value. You will need to make a mutating method instead of a read only computed property. You need to constraint your keys to StringLiteralConvertible type, try something like this:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible {
    mutating func postDic(value: Value) {
        guard
            let timeKey = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970.description as? Key

        else {return}
        self[timeKey] = value
    }
}


var dic:[String:AnyObject] = [:]


dic.postDic("Test")

print(dic)  // "["1446650572.81642": Test]\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "String" for all type of Index. 
You should know that the Key can be an Int, a String or whatever you want. 
Don't give a type in your extension.

Comment: tempDic is Dictionary,["v":"xxxxx"]should right I think

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary` is a generic type.  In fact it is `Dictionary<Key: Hashable, Value>`, where `Key` can be of any type that adopts `Hashable` protocol.

Here:

```
tempDic["v"] = v
```

... you try to assign `v` value to key `"v"` as if you know that both `Key` and `Value` will always be `String`, which is not the case.  That's why the error.

In order to fix this, you should either make the computed property `postDic` to be able to handle all sorts of keys and values, or limit your extension to the specific types of `Key` and `Value` by using `where` clause.

Which of the options to choose depends on what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: it's means use 'if var _ =String(timestamps) {...} '?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question.

Comment: I think tempDic["xxx"] = "xxxxx" must be right but not.i don't know why

Comment: Because you are extending generic `Dictionary` and not `Dictionary<String, String>` (a.k.a. as `[String: String]`).

But let's not dwell on that.  What are you trying to achieve?  (Your code above has other issues too).

Comment: I have a Dictionary,it will add timestamps and sign to connect my server.I want do it like this  `let dic = xxx.postDic`.